# Row selection combining condition on index and condition on a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to select rows from a dataframe based on values in the index combined with values in a specific column:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [0, 20, 30], [40, 20, 30]], 
                  index=[4, 5, 6, 7], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])


    A   B   C
4   0   2   3
5   0   4   1
6   0  20  30
7  40  20  30
```

With

```py
df.loc[df['A'] == 0, 'C'] = 99
```

I can select all rows with column `A = 0` and replace the value in column `C` with 99, but how can I select all rows with column `A = 0` and the `index < 6`. In other words, I want to combine selection on the index with selection on the column.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use multiple conditions in your `loc` statement:

```
df.loc[(df.index < 6) & (df.A == 0), 'C'] = 99
```

Comment: Is pandas actually smart so that it first selects  on the index (faster, hash table, etc.) and only afterwards in the selected subset looking for `df.A == 0`?

Comment: @Peruz It is not. The search expressions `(df.index < 6)` and `(df.A == 0)` each independently create boolean series as masks of the data, and the `&` operator combines them.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical method is to reduce all boolean conditions into a single boolean condition and filter the frame by it.

So for the task at hand, to filter a dataframe by a condition on its index and its columns, write two boolean conditions and reduce into one using `&` (as suggested by @sacuL).

Some alternative methods:

- `eval()` may be used for a readable condition

  ```py
  df.loc[df.eval('index < 6 and A == 0'), 'C'] = 99
  ```
- A function may be passed to `loc`:

  ```py
  df.loc[lambda x: (x.index < 6) & (x['A']==0), 'C'] = 99
  ```