# Parsing data using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have a CSV file which I opened using Pandas and I need to check if a field is missing a file.
For example, I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'path')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
for row in df.iterrows():
    if len(df['Country']) < 1:
        print (row)
```

The input file looks like:

```
Country,"Avg(Mbit/s)Ookla"
Canada,75.18
South Korea,117.95
Netherlands,108.33
Japan,44.05
Norway,134.73
Singapore,67.99
Australia,76.52
Switzerland,82.29
Belgium,58.65
Croatia,86.48
New Zealand,49.49
Austria,56.6
Denmark,105.65
Lithuania,50.13
Czech Republic,44.55
United Arab Emirates,135.35
,41.32
```

So I'll have to check if Country is missing a Value and do something or if the Country is missing the AVG and do something else.

Here's like a complete placeholder code of the whole operation:

```
import pandas as pd
from api_data import APIData
api_data = APIData()

otherfile = api_data.get_content(api_data.get_token({
connection details ...
}))

otherfile = [row.split(',') for row in data]

otherdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
otherdf.drop(9, inplace=True, axis=1)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)


data = pd.read_csv(r'path')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
for row in df.iterrows():
    if (df[df["Country"].isna()]) == True:
        df.drop(row)
    elif (df[df["Avg(Mbit/s)Ookla"].isna()]) == True:
        for otherrow in otherfile.itterrows():
            if (df[df["Country"]]) == (otherdf[otherdf["Country"]]):
                avgspeed = ( avgspeed + (otherdf[otherdf["Country"]]) ) / df.count(how many elements was inserted)
                (df[df["Avg(Mbit/s)Ookla"]]) = avgspeed
```

LE: First 5 rows of the DataFrame:

```
  Country  Avg(Mbit/s)Ookla
0         Canada             75.18
1    South Korea            117.95
2    Netherlands            108.33
3          Japan             44.05
4         Norway            134.73
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `print(df[df["Country"].isna()])`

Comment: What do you want to do? something in pandas or external to it? In short what is the expected output a simple True/False or an operation?

Comment: Nice, but what type of value does .isna return ? I need that inside an IF statement.

Comment: The expected output is to delete the rows not containing any Country and if it's missing the AVG SPEED I'll have to lookup in other files on MongoDB or SQL Server to do the average by myself

Comment: Then provide a more explicit description of the process (ideally with placeholder code)

Comment: I edited the post with a complete placeholder code. THX!

Comment: `df[df["Country"].isna()]` is a dataframe (with all the rows of `df` where column `Country` contains a `NaN`), so `if (df[df["Country"].isna()]) == True:` wont work. You shouldn't iterate over the `df` rows but use Pandas methods instead.

Comment: It looks like you're only doing pandas operation in the loop, so better use vectorized code. For this you need to clearly describe the goal (without referring to loops)

Comment: I saw that `if (df[df["Country"].isna()])` is not returning a boolean value but I used just as an example, I'm new to Pandas and Python in generally so... :)) I'm pretty dumb at it

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that we have a sample of the dataframe that can be copied? I do not want to type of your data. 
Show a simple dataframe with both cases of missing data (is it `nan` or `''`?) and how the output should look like. API calls, your local path are not important for your question.

Comment: @Jacob You could use the provided input file: `data = io.StringIO('''<paste file here>'''); df = pd.read_csv(data)`.

Comment: Sry for late answer, I was watching Pandas tutorials :)). I edited the question and copied the first 5 rows from the dataframe, hopefully that's what u wanted. @mozway was asking me to clearly describe the goal so I'll try my best. So, I have multiple files, doesn't matter the location (mongodb, locally, sql server, api) and I have to work between them for parsing/filtering/cleaning. My tasks are applying to a single file (the one that I described) which depends on other files. I will add one more comment,

Comment: continuing, I read the file using Pandas (it's a CSV). The file has only 2 columns, `Country` and `AVG Internet Speed` and I have to: Clean duplicate lines ( I used `df.drop_duplicates()` , I have to drop the rows where `Country` it's NaN and where a row has a `Country` but it's missing the `AVG Internet Speed`, so `AVG Internet Speed` is NaN, I have to lookup in another file (the other file contains all the regions in a `Country` and their `AVG Internet Speed`) and I have to do the arithmetic mean for all the regions where the `Country` coincide and insert it into my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I merged the needed columns from external tables into my table and then:
`inspdf['avgmbit'] = inspdf.groupby(['sub_region'])['avgmbit'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))`

`inspdf` = my dataframe

`avgmbit` = the column which was missing data

`sub_region` = column from external table

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using *pandas index by condition* in google I get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169051/pandas-dataframe-row-selection-combined-condition-index-and-column-values) post on SO

Thus:

```
df=df[(~df['Country'].isna()) | (~df['Avg(Mbit/s)Ookla'] .isna())].copy()
```

Should work. Code is not tested since no example data is provided.

**EDIT**
Changed condition from `np.nan` to pandas equivalent `isna()` according to comment by *Timus*

Comment: I also added a complete placeholder code so that you can understand the whole operation. Thank you very much for your time and help!